# How do I load my scripts into webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've used webpack to bundle my npm dependencies in the past, like jquery, lodash, etc.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to bundle dependencies AND my own scripts?

Loader.js:

```
require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');
require('lodash');
require('react');
require('slider-component.js'); // my component in app folder
```

slider-component.js:

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let data = [
      {
        title: "My Image 1",
        url: "www.facebook.com",
        img: "https://i.imgur.com/jrIXCSJ.jpg",
        caption: "Something important text"
      },
    ]

    setTimeout(function(){
      this.setState({data: data});
    }, 5000)
  };

  render() {
    let data = this.state.data
    let slides = data.map((slide, index)=> {
      return(<Slide
        key={index}
        title={slide.title}
        url={slide.url}
        img={slide.img}
        caption= {slide.caption}
      />)
    })
    return (
      <ul className="slides">
        {slides}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Slider />,
  document.getElementById('flexslider')
);
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in ./app/loader.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve
>   module 'slider-component.js' in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\projects\sharepoint-projects\addin-slider\app
>   @ ./app/loader.js 10:0-30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this document](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html) relating to how webpack resolve modules.

There are three types of module requests:

1) Absolute path `require("/home/me/file")` `require("C:\Home\me\file")`

2) Relative path `require("../src/file")` `require("./file")`

3) Module path `require("module")` `require("module/lib/file")`

### Absolute path

> We first check if the path points to a directory. For a directory we need to find the main file in this directory. Therefore the `main` field in the `package.json` is joined to the path. If there is no `package.json` or no `main` field, index is used as filename.
>
> We have an absolute path to a file now. We try to append all extensions (configuration option `resolve.extensions`). The first existing file is used as result.

### Relative path

> The context directory is the directory of the resource file that contains the `require` statement. If there is no resource file the configuration option `context` is used as context directory. (This can occur for entry points or with loader-generated files).
>
> The relative path is joined to the context directory and the resulting absolute file is resolved according to “Resolving an absolute path”.

### Module path

> For resolving a module we first gather all search directories for modules from the context directory. This process is similar to the node.js resolving process, but the search directories are configurable with the configuration option `resolve.modulesDirectories`. In addition to this the directories in the configuration option `resolve.root` are prepended and directories in the configuration option `resolve.fallback` are appended.
>
> The module is looked up in each module directory and resolved according to “Resolving an absolute path”. If the first match has no success, the second is tried and so on.

---

The type of module request you want to use is a module path. So, in your `webpack.config.js`, you should add/edit the field `resolve.modulesDirectories` (which is an array of strings) and append the directories that contain your modules.

For example:

```
var path = require('path');

// ...
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        path.resolve('./src/my_components')
    ]
}
```

Also, as the document states, you may use `resolve.root` or `resolve.fallback` to specify these directories.

Comment: Works perfectly and thanks for the great explanation.